# How to proxify the instanciation of array with literal notation []

Tags: javascript, arrays, proxy-pattern

I can detect new instance made via Array() or new Array(). But what about [] ?

```
const originalArray = Array;
Array = new Proxy(Array,{
    construct(target, args) {
        console.log('new array');
        const newArray = Reflect.construct(originalArray, args);
        return newArray;
    },
    apply(target,thisArg,argArray){
        console.log('apply');
        Reflect.apply(target,thisArg,argArray);
    }
});

var a = [3,2];// no handler
var b = Array(3,2);// apply
var c = new Array(3,2);// new
```

Comment: The literal notation `[]` is a shortcut that directly constructs a array without any overrides the constructor might have had. Trying to proxy all arrays seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: hmm, ok too bad..

Comment: What are you actually trying to do that involves proxying arrays? There might be an alternative like creating `class MyArray extends Array`.

Comment: Yep, it was to use proxy handler but with syntax sugar of []

Comment: That would be the Y solution.

Comment: Yep, and if Y solution is not working I know how to do it differently then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to intercept object creation from literal syntax.

In fact, this was possible earlier due to a bug, which caused information leaks by making [JSON vulnerable to hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/).

Comment: too bad, they should have forbid cross-origin script load `<script src="http://example.com/Home/AdminBalances"></script>` rather than the contructor interception (for legit same origin code) imho

Comment: @8HoLoN Forbidding cross-origin script load would break the web. Everyone does it.

Comment: they should only allow it for script like it works for fetch/ajax/xmlhttprequest (with header from server for allowing cross origin when needed )